# Bootstrap menu dropdown issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing an horizontal menu just like the bootstrap but I have a problem when inside the menu I have a dropdown.
This is a code example, as you see the dropdown opens beyond the with of the body. I would like if does not fit the the right, then it will open to the left. I hope you can understand me.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-submenu").on("click",function(e){
    var current=$(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first();
    console.log(current);
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


 $(document).click(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu").hide('slow'); 
});


});
```

Comment: Can't understand your problem. Will you please elaborate this line? "I would like if does not fit the the right, then it will open to the left"

Comment: Ok sorry for my bad english. The thing is when I click to the menu everything looks perfect, but when I click on a dropdown (multilevel menu) the box appears to the right, but is not visible because make an horizontal scroll, and I would like the box open to the right or to the left depending if the page has enough space to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-submenu").on("click", function(e) {
    var current = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first();
    current.toggle();
    if ($('body')[0].scrollWidth > $('body')[0].clientWidth) {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('on-left');
    }
    console.log(current);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide('slow');
  });
});
```

and css,

```
.dropdown-menu.on-left{
      left: -100% !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The above code checks, whether the screen size is exceeding the original size, and if it does, the script adds ac class `on-left` to dropdown.

**condition:**
`$('body')[0].scrollWidth > $('body')[0].clientWidth`

Here's the Pen,
https://codepen.io/lokesh_coder/pen/RRJqWN

Thanks!

Comment: It´s not working when I copy and paste to my html code :(, seems like the $('body')[0].scrollWidth = $('body')[0].clientWidth is always equal.

Comment: You are getting scroll bar on child dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes when I click the dropdown-submenu item I am getting an horizontal scroll.

Comment: Can you check running that condition in your dev console,? Before and after opening the submenu..

Comment: Let me try to do a Pen with my Html

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful

Comment: If you go to the Item Menu "Informate" and make click to dropdown items, you will see the box opens to the right instead to the left.

Comment: Which browser do you use? I have Mozilla and it´s not working :(

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I am also trying but is strange works in Chrome and not in Mozilla :(  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this class `pull-left` for this class `dropdown-submenu`

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu  pull-left">
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding on UX aspects. The best practice would be, if you have menu items aligned to the right side then the submenu should align to the left side. Probably something like "Lalji Tadhani" suggested.